# How can I display the sale from the country?

Tags: c#, linq, oop

The question asks to display the total sale which is group by sales person and filter for only sales made within Asia.

Here is my code I have tried:

```
 var reqtwo = list1
    .GroupBy(p => p.salesPerson)
    .Select(s => new {
            salesperson=  s.Key,
            totalSale = s.Sum(p => p.qty*p.price),
            asia = s.Where(c => c.country =="China" && c.country == "Hongkong" && c.country == "Malaysia" && c.country =="Indonesia" && c.country =="India")
                    })
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.totalSale)
    .ToList();
grid2.DataSource = reqtwo;
```

The result is displaying the total sales of all country not in Asia.

Comment: Are you sure that the countries have to be connected via `&&`? Wouldn't `||` make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

The `Where` needs to be before the `GroupBy`

```
var reqtwo = list1
        .Where(c => c.country =="Chiana" || c.country == "Hongkong" || c.country == "Malaysia" || c.country =="Indonesia" || c.country =="India")
        .GroupBy(p => p.salesPerson)
        .Select(s => new {
                    salesperson=  s.Key,
                    totalSale = s.Sum(p => p.qty*p.price)
                })
        .OrderByDescending(p => p.totalSale)
        .ToList();
```

Ive also changed your `&&` to `||` as a country cannot be China & India at the same time (for example)

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try.